# Laravel phpunit always 404

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

Environment: PHP 7.0  macOS  apache

The code is :

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->visit('/');
}
```

Run phpunit.
The result is:

```
1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
A request to [http://localhost] failed. Received status code [404].
```

It's always normal when in Chrome.

Comment: Are you using vagrant or any VM?

Comment: no..........................

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue, it is by using the url provided by

```
php artisan serve
```

Please visit this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55325789/8414995) for more info

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit your `TestCase.php` file and update

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost'
```

with

```
protected $baseUrl = 'HOST OR URL THAT YOU USE TO ACCESS YOUR SITE'
```