# Laravel phpunit returns 404

Tags: laravel, phpunit

i am new in Laravel. Using local development environment with Homestead
Try to run simple test

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

routes/web.php :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

running phpunit returns 404 error

> vagrant@homestead:~/code/laravel$ phpunit PHPUnit 6.4.3 by Sebastian
>   Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .F.                                                                 3
>   / 3 (100%)
>
> Time: 1.07 seconds, Memory: 10.00MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) Tests\Feature\UserTest::testBasicTest Expected status code 200 but
>   received 404. Failed asserting that false is true.
>
> /home/vagrant/code/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:78
>   /home/vagrant/code/laravel/tests/Feature/UserTest.php:25

I have tried to fix it with these ways

1.
    [Laravel phpunit always 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391255/laravel-phpunit-always-404)
    updateTestCase.php

```
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost'

change with

    protected $baseUrl = 'http://laravel.local'
```

2.
https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/540 and next to it
    https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/571

```
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
    class BankTest extends TestCase {
        use WithoutMiddleware;
```

3. Changing APP_URL in .env to

   ```
   APP_URL=laravel.local
   ```

none of this helped

'laravel.local' works fine in browser

Please, help me fix it

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: @FatBoyXPC, added routes to question

Comment: Which version of Laravel is this?

Comment: @FatBoyXPC, 5.5.19

Comment: Have you tried putting http:// in front or the url in APP_URL? I tried to run my tests without http:// and they failed. I don't have $baseUrl in my TestCase at all, just FYI.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC, adding 'http://' in APP_URL change error code from 404 to 500:Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

Comment: Looks like you're on to a different error now :) I'd have to see all of the code involved to help you figure that out. This looks like your test is working, though!

Comment: Right answer was in /storage/logs/laravel.log, when i run the test, in this log was testing.ERROR that explains what happens. I had to replace '<?=' with '<?echo ' construction in my case.

Comment: perfect its working with me 
@FatBoyXPC

Comment: Write the code line `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` as the first line of your test class method `testBasicTest()`. This will give you more details about the error behind the `404` status.

Answer (score 25):

I was running my application with following URL in browser.
http://localhost/app/public/

The default unit test having below line was failing. It was getting 404 response instead of 200.

`$response = $this->get('/');
$response->assertStatus(200);`

I changed APP_URL in .env file as below after reading above comments.

`APP_URL=http://localhost`

But I was still getting 404 error. After some trial and errors, I found that I needed to clear config cache.

`php artisan config:cache`

This did the trick and my test started working!!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and if I run laravel with php artisan serve, it has to be:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

The `APP_URL`, has to be exactly the URL of the website.

The website was working, but I didn't have that constant correctly, and PHPUnit was saying all time 404.

Don't forget to clear the cache, after change the config

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: You may need to run "php artisan config:cache" too

Answer (score 6):

Laravel tests run and expect environment variables. They expect variables like `ENV_URL`, `ENV_KEY`,... depending on your test case.
It is important that the `ENV_URL` variable is set to `http://localhost` disregarding your laravel/server setup. Tests work differently here.

Inside `phpunit.xml`, the line `<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>` specifies which testing file to use. `value="testing"` expects a to use the `.env.testing` file, if it exists and fallbacks to `.env`.

There are two approaches that you can do from here on:

### Approach A - Using `.env.testing`:

1. Create a copy of `.env` and name it `.env.testing`.
2. Verfiy that `phpunit.xml` includes the `.env.testing` file, like following `<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`
3. **IMPORTANT** Edit the `.env.testing` to use `APP_URL=http://localhost` as its URL. It doesn't matter under which URL you usually serve your application.
4. Edit other values to reflect your testing environment
5. Delete cache using `php artisan cache:clear`

### Approach B - ENV values in phpunit.xml:

You can harcode all ENV values inside the phpunit.xml, like below

```xml
   ...
    <php>
        <server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>
        <server name="APP_KEY" value="base64:e8+BZAzKrSR/LprdHQ2TfMaw+DOTWYmgpkFkEJHV+zw="/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <server name="DB_HOST" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <!-- More ENV values -->
        ...
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

### Bonus -  Hybrid Approach:

Use the main `.env` file and overwrite the `APP_URL` inside the `phpunit.xml`.
For this, there should not exist an `.env.testing` file or remove `<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>` if it does exist.

```xml
   ...
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>

        <!-- IMPORTANT - Overwrite the APP_URL -->
        <server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/> 

        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone having this problem, use `APP_URL=http://localhost`, this happens if you use vagrant I am not sure for other envs, still investigating.

Comment: This works! Not sure why. I created .env.testing and set the `APP_URL=http://localhost`  even .env is `APP_URL=http://localhost/app/public`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with `process isolation` set to `true` in your `phpunit.xml` file? Our functional tests fail with 404 errors all over the place if we do not have process isolation:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
 backupStaticAttributes="false"
 bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
 colors="true"
 convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
 convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
 convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
 processIsolation="true"
 stopOnFailure="false">
```

Comment: I ran into this same issue and am still struggling to get a full understanding as to why (since I have other very similar tests that work fine). If you want to just run processIsolation on a few tests, you can add this in a docblock comment above the test `@runInSeparateProcess`

Comment: I got OK for the first test and 404 for everything else. After 1 hour of searching, I found you answer and I could fix it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to simply test using the url returned by

```
php artisan serve
```

as base url then run the tests

For example:

```
    $response = $this->post('http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/register', [
        'email' => '',
        'phone' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'c_password' => '',
        'role_id' => '',
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(401);
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave `APP_URL` blank in .env file ie

`APP_URL=`

Answer (score 0):

As @TooCooL mentioned, one could set `APP_URL=http://localhost` even if your project might be something as `APP_URL=http://localhost/myproject`.
Even better is to create another `.env`, it shall be called `env.testing` and there one can change APP_URL or even another database for testing purposes only and so on.
Phpunit will look for configuration at that file `.env.testing`
Although phpunit works fine even when APP_URL is set on my vhost name on my lamp stack.
Check out your /etc/hosts file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for Laravel 8 devs.

Use full url inside **get** method

```
 $response = $this->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

Answer (score 0):

In relation to [whiterook6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977524/whiterook6) answer.

**Possible Issue:**
You are using `require_once` or `include_once` to include your routes ([bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use))

**Explanation:**
When `processIsolation="false"`, all test are run by the same process.

In case you have a lot of grouped routes in different files (for example in your web/api.php) using `require_once`, the routes are only loaded once. If your request is done in your first Test it will likely work, but not in the following Tests.

Running a single test is likely to work in this case:

```
php artisan test --filter SecondTest
```

Setting `processIsolation="true"` will create a new instance of the application in which case the require_once is not an issue.

**Fix:**
Changing this your include to `require` or `include` will fix this problem.